# Writting a Java server with multiple UDP connections for each client

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

First of all I’m going to introduce the situation: I’ve created an application that sends video and audio between two Android devices (direct connect between client and server). Now I want to go one step further and use a dedicated Java server running in a computer; this server will have to bridge the traffic between those client and server applications. As an example, at first both android applications will connect with the computer server, then, all the video data obtained from the first device will be sent to the server, and then, sent to the second device.

The quick answer probably will be: Inside the server, create two sockets for each socket existing, and then use them to bridge data. 
The problem is that I have like 5 UDP sockets: Audio Tx and Rx, video Tx and Rx and Orders Tx in the client side, and Audio Tx and Rx, video Tx and Rx and Orders Rx in the server side, I also have a TCP Socket to manage the communication.

So the only option I have at this point is:

### Client APP-----------Computer server-------------Server APP

Audio Tx --------------------------> Audio Rx | Audio Tx -------------------------> Audio Rx

Audio Rx <-------------------------- Audio Tx | Audio Rx <------------------------ Audio Tx

Video Tx --------------------------> Video Rx | Video Tx ------------------------> Video Rx

Video Rx <------------------------- Video Tx | Video Rx <------------------------ Video Tx

Orders Tx ----------------------> Orders Rx | Orders Tx -----------------------> Orders Rx

TCP <-----------------------------------> TCP | TCP <-----------------------------> TCP

Which is an absolute hell to manage/code/maintain.

The second option is the usage of NIO, but it’s not recommended when sending large amounts of data.

Is this the a best way to do this? If not, is there any way to reduce the number of UDP sockets in the server since they will only bridge data between both devices?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: To begin with: I know nothing of UDP. But what comes to the eye for  `Computer server` on first line is `-->Audio Rx | Audio Tx -->`. Is that correct?  I would think more like "-->Audio Tx | Audio Tx -->". I suppose a connection without Computer server would be "Audio Tx --> Audio Tx" ?

Comment: So T is Transmitter/Sender and R is Receiver?

Comment: But do you need that many DIFFERENT R/T sockets in your Computer server? Is relaying audio different from video or orders? The server has nothing else to do than forward incoming packets. So in my opinion you need to program only one RTmodule. Then instantiate it 5 times for your 5 streams.

Comment: This was one of the options, surely I can create a UDPDataBridge class that runs a thread containing two UDP sockets, one for Rx and the other for Tx, then use multiple instances of this class to do the trick, but I was wondering for something more simple than that since the only task is to resend packets. Up to now I will stick to this idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But do you need that many DIFFERENT R/T sockets in your Computer server? Is relaying audio different from video or orders? The server has nothing else to do than forward incoming packets. So in my opinion you need to program only one RTmodule. Then instantiate it 5 times for your 5 streams.